# adding default timezone in php.ini on Lion (Mac)

Tags: php

I have the following problem. I am getting this warning on my php page on my localhost

Message: date() [function.date]: It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings.

I am trying to edit my php.ini file. When i use phpinfo() php function it show that php.ini file is in /etc folder. However, there I have no php.ini file. I have php.in, php.ini-5.2-previous,php.ini.applesaved,php.ini.default,php.ini.default-5.2-previous, but no php.ini

In all those files I enter the following command:date.timezone = Europe/Athens

I try with quotes, without quotes...with single quotes...Nothing. I restart apache after each change, nothing...I restart the computer twice, same story.

Anyone can help with this? Please note that I want to solve this only with adding this command in php.ini

Regards, Zoran

Comment: what if you try copying php.ini.default to php.ini, and adding your setting in there?

Comment: I just did, and it works. warning is gone. I don't understand how it works...but it seems that it works...strange, but....

Answer (score 2):

Mac OS X Lion moves your `php.ini` to `php.ini.applesaved`.

You have to recreate your `php.ini` from `php.ini.default` or from `php.ini.applesaved.`

Answer (score 0):

Copy your default php to a new file, and customize the timezone in there

```
sudo cp /etc/php.ini.default /etc/php.ini
```